# Compiler keeps ignoring cin values ?? help me solve

Tags: c++

I am getting a problem while using

```
 cin >> PayRate
```

and

```
 cin >> H_worked
```

what could be the problem?  Even the compiler doesn't show any errors but when program runs the 2nd and 3rd `cin` values aren't read by compiler.

Program:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int employeeName, H_worked;
    float PayRate, GrossPay, NetPay;
    cout << "Please input your employee's name:";
    cin >> employeeName;
    cout << "Input hourly wage rate:";

    cin >> PayRate;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Input hours worked :";

    cin >> H_worked;
    cout << endl;
    if (H_worked > 40)
    {
        H_worked = H_worked*1.5;
        GrossPay = H_worked*PayRate;
        cout << "Your employees gross pay for this week is" << GrossPay << endl;
        NetPay = GrossPay - (GrossPay* 3.625);
        cout << "Your employees net pay is" << NetPay << endl;
    }
    else (H_worked <= 40);
    {
        GrossPay = H_worked*PayRate;
        cout << "Your employees gross pay for this week is" << GrossPay << endl;
        NetPay = GrossPay - (GrossPay*3.625);
        cout << "And your employees net pay is" << NetPay << endl;
    }
    return 0;
    getch();

}
```

Comment: First of all, you should write your code in such a way that humans can read it. Also, don't use a [tag:c] for a `std::cin` question, that's specific to c++. And finally the compiler has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Why is `employeeName` an `int`?  Are you entering characters there?

Comment: Proper indentation matters. Also you tagged your question [tag:compiler-errors] but your description mentions that the compiler does *not* give any  errors and the program runs. Please fix that. (P.S: *cin values aren't read by compiler* the compiler does not ready any values, it's your program that reads the values. All the compiler does is turn your source code into an executable)

Comment: once your program runs, the compiler does not read anything.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the code indentation.  See how much easier it is to read versus what you had originally?

Comment: Many compilers would warn that the statement `(H_worked <= 40);` (which is your entire `else` branch) has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `employeeName` as an `int` but that does not make any sense as names have letters not numbers.  If you are actually entering in character data then this will cause `cin` to fail and that will make any subsequent call fail as well.  This fits with your description of what is happening.  To fix this first we need to make `employeeName` a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) so we can store letters.

```
int employeeName, H_worked;
//becomes
std::string employeeName;
int H_worked;
```

Then we need to change the input method.  Since a name can have spaces in it we need to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `>>` to get the name as `>>` will stop when it sees a space.

```
cout << "Please input your employee's name:";
std::getline(std::cin, employeeName);
```

You also have a semicolon at the end of your else condition

```
else (H_worked <= 40);
```

This means that

```
{
    GrossPay = H_worked*PayRate;
    cout << "Your employees gross pay for this week is" << GrossPay << endl;
    NetPay = GrossPay - (GrossPay*3.625);
    cout << "And your employees net pay is" << NetPay << endl;
}
```

Will always run as `;` ends the `else` part.

Then we have the issue that you are using non standard includes.  In standard c++

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

Should be

```
#include <iostream>
```

As all standard includes omit the `.h`.  Since all of the standard components live in the `std` namespace you are also going to have to deal with that.  You can either put `std::` in front of all the `std` components or you can put `using std::cout;`, `using std::cin`, ect.  I would not suggest using `using namespace std;` for the reasons outlined in [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)